# SQL: default values for rows not corresponding to a JOIN criterion?

Tags: sql

Say I have a table SESSIONS with two columns - "session_id" and "username" which tells me which user was involved with which session in my site. I also have another table USERS with columns "username" and "country". Now, when I want to know how many sessions came from every country, I do

```
SELECT count(*), sessions.username, users.country
FROM sessions
INNER JOIN users
ON sessions.username=users.username
GROUP BY country
```

Now here's the problem: not every user listed in the SESSIONS table actually has a row in the USERS table. For those users I'd like to write "unknown" for country, but not ignore their sessions completely.

Is there a "correct" way of doing it directly in the SQL query? I can always do some PHP magic after suitable queries, or add users to the USERS table when a row is added to SESSIONS with a user not currently present in USERS, but I am wondering if there is some SQL way of detecting the "missing" rows and assigning some default value to them.

Comment: Invalid group by query... The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called `OUTER` join (as opposed to `INNER`).

More specifically, you can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which returns all rows from the "left" table (`sessions`) even if there is no corresponding row in the "right" table (`users`). In this case the returned values for the `users` table would be `NULL`. You can use standard function `COALESCE` to replace these `NULL` values with some other value, like 'unknown'.

```
SELECT 
    count(*) AS Cnt
    ,COALESCE(users.country, 'unknown') AS Country
FROM 
    sessions
    LEFT JOIN users ON sessions.username=users.username
GROUP BY users.country;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Left Join` to achieve require output

```
SELECT count(*), sessions.username, ISNULL(users.country,'Unknown')
FROM sessions
LEFT JOIN users ON sessions.username=users.username
GROUP BY sessions.username, users.country
```